# use Eval value as a stored procedure parameter - ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Is there a way to perform this in ASP.NET, i'm trying to use the Eval("ID") value as an input parameter to another stored procedure.

For Example:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", Eval("ID"))
```

i know that does not work, but is there a way to get the value of Eval as an input parameter to the stored procedure?

Thanks,

Comment: @ahamad noori check this article https://forums.asp.net/t/1000526.aspx?A+solution+for+Procedure+or+function+has+too+many+arguments+specified+when+you+using+SqlDataSource+with+Stored+Procedure

Comment: Please don't use `.AddWithValue` See http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/
and
https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/
and another one:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/195937/addwithvalue-performance-and-plan-cache-implications
Here is another
https://andrevdm.blogspot.com/2010/12/parameterised-queriesdont-use.html